# Does Voldemort ever apparate?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Did Lord Voldemort ever apparate during the Harry Potter series?  In particular, does he apparate into or out the Ministry of Magic during the battle in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*?

It seems to me that just like Harry, the Dark Lord seems to prefer flying over apparation in general.

Comment: At one point Voldemort apparating is mentioned (whether  in Malfoy Manor or Godric's Hollow I can't remember right now), but I don't think he apparated inside the Minisry, as there are bound to be anti apparition spells as in Hogwarts

Comment: I believe he apparates in the Death Hallows movie when harry chucks him of a building and they go down together.

Comment: @user13267: I believe a lot of Ministry employees apparate to work, so I don’t know if they would have anit-disapparation charms. Further, Dumbledore has to explicitly cast an Anti-Disapparation jinx in *Order of the Phoenix* to keep the Death Eaters in the Death Chamber, suggesting they aren’t there by default.

Comment: No, Voldy is a muggle, don't you know?

Comment: It is a movie scene, and not necessarily from the book (don't know), but Voldemort does disapparate with Nagini during the Battle for Hogwarts when he realized The Lost Diadem had been destroyed. I believe he utters something like "Come, Nagini; I must keep you safe."

Comment: @Awal Garg: no, he is actually a Time Lord.

Comment: He does and so does Dumbledore in the battle in the Ministry @user13267

Comment: ...oh and he also even says that soon he'd be close enough to Malfoy Manor to Apparate. He I also believe does that for the prison where Grindewald is kept. Maybe I should come up with an answer.

Comment: @user13267 In addition to the point about the charm Dumbledore had to place in the Ministry Voldemort himself does so during the duel with Dumbledore; he also is seen by the Ministry including Fudge just as they arrive. So he definitely did Apparate in the Ministry.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**At least once, yes.**

He disapparates from the Ministry at the end of *Order of the Phoenix*, just as the Aurors and Fudge arrive:

> “He was there!” shouted a scarlet-robed man with a ponytail, who was pointing at a pile of golden rubble on the other side of the hall, where Bellatrix had lain trapped only moments before. “I saw him, Mr. Fudge, I swear it was You-Know-Who, he grabbed a woman and Disapparated!”
>
> — *Order of the Phoenix*, chapter 36, *The Only One He Ever Feared*

Of course, flying out of the Ministry is probably impossible.

At least on some occasions, Voldemort prefers to fly due to sheer distance. Harry sees this inside his head when he’s approaching Malfoy Manor in the final book:

> Harry knew it; his scar was bursting with the pain of it, and he could feel Voldemort flying through the sky from far away, over a dark and stormy sea, and soon he would be close enough to Apparate to them, and Harry could see no way out.
>
> — *Deathly Hallows*, chapter 23, *Malfoy Manor*

I don’t think the fact that both Harry and Voldemort prefer flying to apparition is anything except coincidence.

Comment: Doesn't he apparate to them when Hermione and Harry are in Godrics Hollow with Nagini? (I can't quite remember but it may be worth checking out to bolster your answer :))

Comment: @Simon: He arrives in Godric’s Hollow very quickly, but I’ve looked over the passage and I don’t think it says explicitly that he apparated there.

Comment: I think you're definitely right there, for most part it is just insinuated that he apparates. Does anyone mention it when they talk about him appearing at the potters?

Comment: i've read somewhere that apparition over water is unlikely in HP universe, hence why Voldie flies when he is on mainland Europe..can someone verify? :D

Comment: @BP_Phoenix: I don’t recall ever reading anything to that effect.

Comment: @alexwlchan it had something to do with this question, but cannot seem to find anything to substantiate any cannon regarding the apparition over water scenario:http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10236/how-far-can-a-person-apparate

Comment: One small point: The movie differs from the book in that aspect, in the movie Bellatrix is shown sliding into a Flue gateway and disappearing in a green fire rush.

Comment: He also apparates during the battle with Dumbledore in the MoM. So does Dumbledore.

Comment: I've added an answer with quite a few other examples just now. But yes he definitely did Apparate several times.

Comment: @alexwlchan So you're saying Voldemort was right there? If he was do you think he would have taken any time at all? He'd be there. It's also known that Voldemort realised after they were hunting Horcruxes that he had to keep Nagini safe which means not doing other duties but staying beside him. It doesn't explicitly say he Apparated in another part of the duel in the Ministry but he did in fact Apparate there.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. There are several instances where he actually does and there is at least one time when he thinks it (Harry is Voldemort or senses his thoughts) he's close enough to where he can then Apparate.

## The Order of the Phoenix

### The duel with Dumbledore in the Ministry of Magic

Voldemort Apparates in the Ministry atrium. The following examples are from the chapter *The Only One He Ever Feared*:

At first Dumbledore created a flame that wrapped itself around Voldemort; but momentarily the rope because a serpent, released Voldemort who then Disapparated:

> [...] Dumbledore had drawn back his and waved it as though brandishing a whip. A long thin flame flew from the tip; it wrapped itself around Voldemort, shield and all.
>
> For a moment, it seemed Dumbledore had won, but then the fiery rope became a serpent, which relinquished its hold upon Voldemort at once and turned, hissing furiously, to face Dumbledore. **Voldemort vanished.** The snake reared from the floor, ready to strike — There was a burst of flame in midair above Dumbledore **just as Voldemort reappeared**, standing on the plinth in the middle of the pool where so recently the five statues had stood.

Voldemort also Disapparates just as the Aurors arrive (just after):

> 'Yes,' said Harry, shaking so violently he could not hold his head up properly. 'Yeah, I’m — where’s Voldemort, where — who are all these — what’s —'
>   The Atrium was full of people. The floor was reflecting emerald- green flames that had burst into life in all the fireplaces along one wall, and a stream of witches and wizards was emerging from them. As Dumbledore pulled him back to his feet, Harry saw the tiny gold statues of the house-elf and the goblin leading a stunned-looking Cornelius Fudge forward.
>
> 'He was there!' shouted a scarlet-robed man with a ponytail, who was pointing at a pile of golden rubble on the other side of the hall, where Bellatrix had lain trapped moments before. 'I saw him, Mr. Fudge, I swear, **it was You-Know-Who, he grabbed a woman and Disapparated!**'

### Complementing the above: Dumbledore casts an anti-Disapparation spell to prevent the escape of Death Eaters before he duels Voldemort.

When Dumbledore arrives at the Ministry at the end of The Order of the Phoenix he casts an anti-Disapparation spell so that the Death Eaters could not Disapparate away. Only Bellatrix is saved because she was in the atrium and Voldemort took the time to rescue her (although the film portrays it as if she was gone during the battle in the book she was pinned magically by a statue by Dumbledore) as I cited above. He tells Fudge that there were Death Eaters in the Ministry after Voldemort Disapparates with Bellatrix just as Fudge and the Aurors arrive in the Ministry:

> 'If you proceed **downstairs into the Department of Mysteries**, Cornelius,' said Dumbledore, apparently satisfied that Harry was all right, and walking forward so that the newcomers realised he was there for the first time (a few of them raised their wands, others simply looked amazed; the statues of the elf and goblin applauded and Fudge jumped so much that his slipper-clad feet left the floor), 'you will find several escaped Death Eaters contained in the Death Chamber, **bound by an Anti-Disapparation Jinx** and awaiting your decision as to what to do with them.'

## The Deathly Hallows

Voldemort also Apparates in The Deathly Hallows; Harry also reads his thoughts when he says to himself that he would soon be close enough to Apparate. The following examples are those I can think of off the top of my head:

### The Battle of the Seven Potters

At the end of the Battle of the Seven Potters just after Voldemort's wand (which means Lucius' wand) was destroyed by Harry's wand he tells Selwyn to give him (Voldemort) his wand. However at this point Harry and Hagrid arrive at a safe house and Voldemort disappears. It's true he can make himself invisible but it's unlikely this is the case because he had no reason to stay there:

> He felt Voldemort before he saw him. Looking sideways, he stared into the red eyes and was sure they would be the last thing he ever saw: Voldemort preparing to curse him once more — And then **Voldemort vanished.**

And indeed Voldemort did not return then; Harry was surprised at this:

> He could not understand **where Voldemort had gone and expected him to swoop out of the darkness at any moment.**

But Voldemort *did not* swoop out of the darkness which means he indeed did Disapparate because he (Voldemort) knew it would be impossible to get through until the Ministry had fallen (but see below). Harry realises this shortly after:

> Now Harry understood why Voldemort had vanished; it had been at the point when the motorbike crossed the barrier of the Order’s charms.

In addition though Harry reckons that Voldemort Apparated to the Death Eaters that recognised Harry:

> Harry explained briefly how the Death Eaters pursuing them had seemed to recognise him as the true Harry, how they had abandoned the chase, how they must have **summoned Voldemort, who had appeared** just before he and Hagrid had reached the sanctuary of Tonks’s parents.

Whilst it's not clear if he did indeed Apparate I think it's quite probable he did esp because he knew he was short on time; after all Voldemort had already had a wand destroyed and certainly they would be at safe house soon.

### The subject of the word 'vanish' versus 'Apparate' just after Harry and Hagrid reach the safe house

Alex suggested in the comments that the word *vanish* might not be indicative of Voldemort Apparating. This is admittedly something I thought of and I had similar reasoning: that Voldemort might well have tried to penetrate the defences even if only momentarily; he wasn't one to give up easily after all and he knew magic that nobody else did. It could be interpreted that reaching the safe house the two of them couldn't see each other due to the defences set up. But whether or not Voldemort Apparated at that moment what is certain is he would have Apparated once he realised he could not penetrate the defences. Of course Harry was also moved to the Burrow not long after that.

The beauty of the imagination is that you can interpret things in different ways from people reading the same thing but does it matter much if you look at it differently but enjoy it that way? I don't think so; that takes the magic away from reading and that's not something I would ever do deliberately. If you want to interpret 'vanish' as Apparate you can; if you don't want to that's also fine: Alex cited a quote that can also be interpreted different ways. In my mind when Harry imagines Voldemort it's not the same as when he is or feels Voldemort there.

Either way though Voldemort would have Apparated away once he found out he couldn't get through. Is there literal proof? Perhaps not but he wouldn't have wasted his time flying when he could Disapparate would he?

### Godric's Hollow

Voldemort also Apparates just as Harry and Hermione flee Godric's Hollow:

> **And then his scar burst open and he was Voldemort and he was running across the foetid bedroom, his long white hands clutching at the windowsill as he glimpsed the bald man and the little woman twist and vanish**, and he screamed with rage, a scream that mingled with the girl’s, that echoed across the dark gardens over the church bells ringing in Christmas Day. . . .

And Harry thinks again on it two days later:

> After two nights of little sleep, Harry’s senses seemed more alert than usual. Their **escape from Godric’s Hollow had been so narrow** that Voldemort seemed somehow closer than before, more threatening.

### Malfoy Manor

Harry is Voldemort as the trio are in Malfoy Manor; Voldemort had been summoned and this is what Harry witnesses:

> Harry knew it; his scar was bursting with the pain of it, and he could feel Voldemort flying through the sky from far away, over a dark and stormy sea, and **soon he would be close enough to Apparate** to them, and Harry could see no way out.

### Summary

I do not know if there are other examples but the above are quite a few instances where he does Apparate. It makes sense too doesn't it when you think about it? He was the most brilliant student Hogwarts had ever seen and there were numerous times Voldemort was called and he would want to get there as quickly as possible. The only way to do that would be to Apparate; that is to say the quickest way would be to Apparate. This includes at least once in battle with Dumbledore as I cited earlier.

Comment: I don't think the example from outside Tonks's house is indicative of Apparition. Voldemort was still there; he just "vanished" in the sense that Harry could no longer see him because Voldemort couldn't proceed (because of the protective enchantments). Note that Harry seems to know this: *He imagined Voldemort, a hundred yards above them as they spoke, looking for a way to penetrate what Harry visualized as a great transparent bubble.*

Comment: @Alex **Imagined** It's not reality. Big difference. Thank you for fixing the spelling errors. In my editor I by mistake a long while back added the incorrect spelling to Lucius and I tend to forget to update it (and have too much going on to bother). However the part you took out completely then takes part of the context away so I will add that back. Anyway imagination is very different from actually experiencing it. Right. You added it to the next paragraph. Not sure why though since the book (at least digital copy I was using as the book isn't right here) I thought had it in the first.

Comment: The part I took out completely was doubled. I took out one version of it, but all the content is still in the post.

Comment: @Alex Right. I just noticed that it was moved down to the bottom. Then I looked at the second paragraph and thought you moved it. But it was already there hence the diff output not showing it added. As I said I have a lot going on. I can take a guess at how that repeat happened but anyway thanks for the fixes. Appreciate it.

Comment: He imagined Voldemort there because he assumed that Voldemort was still there. There would have been no reason for Voldemort to leave the second Harry crossed the protection border. He was bound to try to break through for a bit.

Comment: @Alex And you know what they say about those who assume, yes? The other times he absolutely knows if Voldemort is there and it's not imagining but inside his (Voldemort's) head. Just because Voldemort might have tried finding it doesn't mean he did. Furthermore the quote that follows where Harry understands suggests that he did indeed Apparate or more correctly that his initial thought / imagination was wrong. Whatever the case there's this to consider: **once Voldemort couldn't penetrate the defences do you think he walked or flew away? Both would be a waste of time.**

Comment: I'm not arguing that Voldemort didn't Apparate. I'm just pointing out that his "vanishing" is not evidence of Apparition. That other forms of travel are less efficient than Apparition is a general argument that Voldemort is an Apparater, but it doesn't constitute an example of him actually Apparating.

Comment: @Alex I just updated the answer to try and address this. Feel free to comment on it. I actually did see before that vanish could be interpreted a number of ways but I also know that he would have Apparated once he was certain he couldn't have got through but as I note the imagination is a beautiful thing.

Comment: I thank you for addressing my points in the post, but I stand by my last comment. You are essentially arguing that even if it doesn't actually say that Voldemort Apparated, we can assume that he Apparated because Apparition is more efficient. If that is the argument then no examples of Apparition are necessary. It is simply a logical argument that doesn't require any examples. Therefore, citing examples that are only examples of Apparition *if we already grant the logical argument* doesn't strengthen the argument.

Comment: @Alex Yes. I concede with you there. I thought I made that clear but maybe not; it's quite possible I didn't with all that's going on in my life right now. I think what I was trying to say is that the word vanish doesn't imply Apparation but it's almost certain (and I think you and I both know it is certain it's just you can't use it as an example, right?) that he did Apparate after he couldn't get through. But as for an example where it says that he absolutely did then you're quite correct. Thanks.

Comment: (I hope everything works out with whatever's going on in your life, and that my comments haven't contributed to any problems.) This is where I distinguish between the facts and the question. I would not have asked the question, because I don't see any reason to think that Voldemort wouldn't Apparate. Even if we never saw him Apparate it wouldn't mean much because we are very limited in what we see of Voldemort. That said, it is the questioner's prerogative to ask if there any actual examples of him Apparating. So I agree with your conclusions, but I just think that nothing is an **cont.**

Comment: **cont.** actual example of Apparation unless it is expressly indicated as such in the text. By extension, if I was answering the question I would only cite examples where it is conclusive from the text that Apparition occurred (or where there was some argument to be made that he Apparated that was not based on the general argument of "of course Voldemort was an Apparater", e.g. he was seen on opposite ends of the world in a very short span of time). Of course, though, this is just my opinion and there is no need for you to accept it.

Comment: @Alex No - it's nothing to do with you or anyone here; nor is there any fault in it. There have been four deaths in the family since late January and my girlfriend is extremely unwell. You have a valid point of not including an example where it might not be. I included it because it's how I Interpreted it at first. I could edit it out but I think my edit should suffice. What to you is evidence of Apparate? Does Voldemort in the duel with Dumbledore Apparate? I agree though: of course he Apparates. But they probably are after what you say: *unless it's expressly indicated as such by the text*