# How did Hermione's parents get to Australia?

Tags: harry-potter

Hermione had modified her parents memories, and they were convinced that they were called Wendell and Monica Wilkins.

**How did they get to Australia?** If they go by plane, they had to go to the airport, and they need to go through passport checks. Did Hermione modify their names on their passport as well? If she didn't, wouldn't the people who are checking their passports be able to realise that the names are wrong?

Comment: Perhaps she Apparated them?? But that would certainly contradict the nice scene in the film.

Comment: In the film, the pictures changed. Presumably their passports did as well,

Comment: They simply turned anti-clockwise about 17.3 times, found a crocodile, wrestled it, and finally said the phrase "That's not a knife... *this* is a knife". That's how we get back to Australia usually.

Comment: @ThruGog - You can't apparate those sorts of distances.

Comment: Them magic chimneys, they bring da flame and movement!

Comment: @Valorum I don't think the distance of Apparation is a problem, since [Pottermore's History of Magic in North America](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en) says that wizards were able to Apparate between Europe and North America. What would stop them from going all the way across the world?

Comment: @ThruGog I'm not sure Hermione would have Apparated them because she made it so "their life's ambition is to move to Australia, which they now have done" (DH, The Goul in Pajamas chapter). It sounds like they moved themselves. If she Apparated them over, she could have just made them think they lived in Australia all along, couldn't she? I doubt they would even let her Apparate them anyways, as her parents or as the Wilkins!

Comment: @Dumbledorality - Australia is rather farther than America, ignoring the fact that it might take multiple jumps to get to a distant location.

Comment: @Valorum I guess you're right. I just found [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10246/73542) to a question about Apparating that says while it is possible to Apparate such distances, Hermione wouldn't dare attempt it having learned how to Apparate only a few months before, as well as take two muggles who have probably never Apparated before.

Comment: I think you're all correct about Apparition. However, I think she must have used her magical skill rather than Muggle administration, applying for passports etc. I think it takes too long!

Answer (score 2):

I think Hermione must have altered not just their passports, but all their identification and to their new names.

Her parents would not have been able to start a new life without that I'D.

I think the magic to change names would have been well within her grasp. She only needs to fool muggles

Comment: So I think they went by plane with altered passports.

Answer (score 1):

Dumbledore took away young Tom Riddle from an orphanage by showing a white paper

> There was no doubt that Mrs. Cole was an inconveniently sharp woman. Apparently Dumbledore thought so too, for Harry now saw him slip his wand out of the pocket of his velvet suit, at the same time picking up a piece of perfectly blank paper from Mrs. Cole's desktop.
>
> "Here," said Dumbledore, waving his wand once as he passed her the piece of paper, "I think this will make everything clear."
>
> Mrs. Cole's eyes slid out of focus and back again as she gazed intently at the blank paper for a moment.
>
> "That seems perfectly in order," she said placidly, handing it back.

Although there is absolutely no evidence, it is pretty believable that Hermione might have done something like this with the passports, if she wasn't able to forge convincing fake ones.

Comment: Sorry, but this appears to be evidence not of a magicked piece of paper, but **a muggle who's been mackicked to believe that a blank piece of paper is some kind of paperwork**.

Comment: I don't think so. If Dumbledore just wanted a "Jedi trick" effect, why would he need the piece of paper?
Anyway, again, all of this is and will always remain opinion-based, unless J.K.R. answers herself

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to make her believe that she's reading something if she's holding a piece of paper rather than *firstly making her believe that she's holding a piece of paper*, **then** making her believe that she's reading something on it. Either way, the spell seems to be directed at her, not the paper.

Comment: Holy crap. I read Half Blood Prince at least three times and never realized Dumbledore used a psychic paper!! He was a Timelord!!